# wp_rewrite in a WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, wordpress

Ok, I've got this code that I've been using to spit out news to an application of mine.  It was working until today.  I've cutout all the logic in the following code to make it simpiler.  But it should "WORK"  Can someone help me fix this code to where it works, and is done right?  I know it's hacked together , but it didn't seem to have any problems until today.  I have not updated anything, don't know what the deal is.

```
 Plugin Name:   MyPlugin Example
 Version:       1.0.1


If ( ! class_exists("MyPlugin") )
{
    class MyPlugin
    {
        var $db_version = "1.0"; //not used yet

        function init()
        {
   //Nothing as of now.
        }
        function activate()
        {
            global $wp_rewrite;
            $this->flush_rewrite_rules();
        }

        function pushoutput( $id )
        {
            $output->out =' The output worked!';
            $this->output( $output );

        }
        function output( $output )
        {
            ob_start();
            ob_end_clean();
            header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate' );
            header( 'Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
            header( 'Content-type: application/json' );

            echo json_encode( $output );
            //Must encode this...
        }

        function flush_rewrite_rules()
        {
            global $wp_rewrite;
            $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
        }

        function createRewriteRules( $rewrite )
        {
            global $wp_rewrite;
            $new_rules = array( 'MyPlugin/(.+)' => 'index.php?MyPlugin=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) );
            if ( ! is_array($wp_rewrite->rules) )
            {
                $wp_rewrite->rules = array();
            }
            $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
            return $wp_rewrite;
        }


        function add_query_vars( $qvars )
        {
            $qvars[] = 'MyPlugin';
            return $qvars;
        }
        function template_redirect_intercept()
        {
            global $wp_query;
            if ( $wp_query->get('MyPlugin') )
            {
                $id = $wp_query->query_vars['MyPlugin'];
                $this->pushoutput( $id );


                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
If ( class_exists("MyPlugin") )
{
    $MyPluginCode = new MyPlugin();
}
If ( isset($MyPluginCode) )
{
    register_activation_hook( __file__, array($MyPluginCode, 'activate') );
    add_action( 'admin-init', array(&$MyPluginCode, 'flush_rewrite_rules') );
    //add_action( 'init', array(&$MyPluginCode, 'init') );
    add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', array(&$MyPluginCode, 'createRewriteRules') );

    add_action( 'template_redirect', array(&$MyPluginCode, 'template_redirect_intercept') );
    // add_filter( 'query_vars', array(&$MyPluginCode, 'add_query_vars') );
}
```

Comment: I basically just need to be able to take the input from a URL and output some JSON data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I changed a little bit of your code in the process, but this worked for me:

```
<?php

/**
* Plugin Name:   MyPlugin Example
* Version:       1.0.1
**/
class MyPlugin {

    function activate() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $this->flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    // Took out the $wp_rewrite->rules replacement so the rewrite rules filter could handle this.
    function create_rewrite_rules($rules) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $newRule = array('MyPlugin/(.+)' => 'index.php?MyPlugin='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1));
        $newRules = $newRule + $rules;
        return $newRules;
    }

    function add_query_vars($qvars) {
        $qvars[] = 'MyPlugin';
        return $qvars;
    }

    function flush_rewrite_rules() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }

    function template_redirect_intercept() {
        global $wp_query;
        if ($wp_query->get('MyPlugin')) {
            $this->pushoutput($wp_query->get('MyPlugin'));
            exit;
        }
    }

    function pushoutput($message) {
        $this->output($message);
    }

    function output( $output ) {
        header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate' );
        header( 'Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );

        // Commented to display in browser.
        // header( 'Content-type: application/json' );

        echo json_encode( $output );
    }
}

$MyPluginCode = new MyPlugin();
register_activation_hook( __file__, array($MyPluginCode, 'activate') );

// Using a filter instead of an action to create the rewrite rules.
// Write rules -> Add query vars -> Recalculate rewrite rules
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', array($MyPluginCode, 'create_rewrite_rules'));
add_filter('query_vars',array($MyPluginCode, 'add_query_vars'));

// Recalculates rewrite rules during admin init to save resourcees.
// Could probably run it once as long as it isn't going to change or check the
// $wp_rewrite rules to see if it's active.
add_filter('admin_init', array($MyPluginCode, 'flush_rewrite_rules'));
add_action( 'template_redirect', array($MyPluginCode, 'template_redirect_intercept') );
```

I've commented the important parts, but what I did was basically to move your hooks over to `use_filter` rather than `add_action`. I also moved the filters into the order that they are actually used in Wordpress. Seemed the thing to do at the time.

Finally, make sure that your permalinks are set to use pretty URLs. I had an issue where mine were set to default, which makes Wordpress ignore any rewrite conditions that it would otherwise need to parse. Change over to some pretty URLs and your conditions will refresh.

Let me know if that works for you. Hope that helps.

Thanks, Joe

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm testing it now!  One question, what would be a proper way of testing the $wp_rewrite rules to see if it's active?

Comment: Usually it's enough to invoke your URL w/o rewrite and with it (/index.php?MyPlugin=foo and /MyPlugin/foo) and use a little trial and error. If not, the rewrite code is in wp-includes/rewrite.php. It's not pretty nor easy to debug with the code in that file, though.

Comment: i know this is old, but i am wondering if this approach can now be updated with flush_rewrite_rules() now?