# Wordpress, .htaccess and mod_rewrite: how can I add redirection rules?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the moment, I have a standard installation of Wordpress 3.0, and the .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to rewrite URLs so that I can provide some automatically generated pages, but keep it within the Wordpress theme. For example, going to `/event/123/` should pull the details for event #123 from my database, without the page existing in Wordpress.

I was thinking I could create a "generic event" page (eg. `/event/generic/`) in Wordpress and have it take a parameter, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^event/(\d+)/$ /event/generic/?q=$1 [L]
```

However, that doesn't seem to work, it just takes me to the Wordpress 404 page. I'm thinking that I might be asking a lot of Wordpress here, but surely it's possible?

The only other solution I've thought of would be to hack 404.php within the theme.

**Update**

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^eventtest/(\w+)/$ /events/event-single/ [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I then go to `/eventtest/testing/`, then:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is /eventtest/testing/
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] is /events/event-single/
```

The `/events/event-single/` page exists in Wordpress, but if I go to `/eventtest/testing/`, I get a 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to even touch your .htaccess - you can do everything you want within WordPress itself!

Check out the [rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) and [my answer on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256888/#3258934).

Comment: +1, this is why the WordPress rewrite rules have been simplified.

Answer (score 0):

That rule looks fine. But make sure that you put that rule in front of Wordpress’ catch-all rule so that a request gets rewritten before it is caught by Wordpress’ last rule. So try:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^event/(\d+)/$ /event/generic/?q=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: I've tried that, and unfortunately it still goes to the Wordpress 404 page. The RewriteRule is OK, because sending it to test.php works just fine. I think the key point here is that I want to redirect to a page that doesn't exist within Wordpress, and 'fake' a page.

For example, if I create a /test/ page in Wordpress, this results in a 404 page:

RewriteRule ^event/(\d+)/$ /test/ [L]

Comment: @Sam Starling: Does */event/generic/* exist at all?

Comment: I've added an example above which should clarify things slightly.