# Rewrite Rule for custom template in WordPress is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, function

I am trying to make a custom URL like "mysite.com/artist/bruno-mars" with a custom template "artist.php", which is in the theme folder.

Here is the "artist.php" template code for example

```
<?php
get_header();
//my custom code goes here //
get_footer();
?>
```

And now in the head of the theme functions.php, I put the code

```
/**
 * Custom rewrite 
 */

add_action( 'init', 'ic_rewrite_rule' );
function ic_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'artist/([^&]+)', 'index.php?artist=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

/**
 * Custom query vars 
 */

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'ic_register_query_var' );
function ic_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'artist';
    return $vars;
}

/**
 * Custom page template 
 */

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ic_url_rewrite_templates' );
function ic_url_rewrite_templates() {
    if ( get_query_var( 'artist' ) )
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() { return get_template_directory() . '/artist.php'; });
}
```

But this is not working. It is showing 404 error. Can anybody help me out.

Here is an example - [Custom rewrite rules in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154340/custom-rewrite-rules-in-wordpress) but not sure, If that might work.

**UPDATE**

I figured it out. Here is code for functions.php in theme folder.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_artistname_var', 0, 1);
function add_artistname_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'artistname';
    return $vars;
}
add_rewrite_rule('^artist/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?pagename=artist&artistname=$matches[1]','top');
```

Comment: Have you regenerate permalink on the back office ?

Comment: no....... back office?

Comment: Go at this url /wp-admin/options-permalink.php