# Create routes and render content from WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, routes, endpoint

I wanted to create a WordPress plugin that would add various routes/endpoints/pages to the WordPress site and content for those routes.
I was looking at various SO posts and various blogs but I did not find the exact answer.

Is there a way to add new routes/endpoints from a plugin and use templates or any other way to have logic for content for those routes/endpoints?

For example, activation of that plugin would add routes:

- "domain.com/something/parameter"

And I would have a special logic that would show content for that "something" route and that parameter "parameter".

Comment: May be you want something like this https://gist.github.com/samhernandez/8062848

Comment: I tried that but it looks like it is not working. Looks like that code works when called directly from the installation folder, not from the plugin.

Comment: Now I tried solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210826/wp-rewrite-in-a-wordpress-plugin and I will see how it goes. For now it looks promising